# Why doesn't "requests" return 404 when the URL does not exist?

Tags: python-requests, http-status-code-404

Using the following

```py
import requests
URLS = [r"http://www.google.com/",
r"https://httpbin.org/status/404",
r"http://www.hajsdgkahsjd.com"]

import requests
for url in URLS:
    print (requests.get(url).status_code)

# 200
# 404
# ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.hajsdgkahsjd.com', port=80):
#Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection #object at 0x00000141C52BB108>: 
#Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

I know I can write a try/catch and return a "404" my self, but why doesn't requests return a 404 code when it cannot find the last URL (since it does not exist)?